# Web based User Authentication System to control session management

Tags: apache, postgresql, security, geoserver

I am new to GIS web development and I have been working on developing browser based application using Postgres, apache and Geoserver which is used to render all GIS data.

I want to build user authorization system on that, so that no one can access Geoserver and also only one session per used id should be there also it should include initially when user registers one time activation should be provided by me, as i can know how many users are using it.

And also if all this is done in single computer, how can i authenticate user ??

Could somebody guide me on this?

Comment: Can you use Spring Security?

Comment: Neil, i dont have any experience in that, I just want that user should not be able to access geoserver locally by typing localhost:8080, even though geoserver is installed in his machine